Convolution product in von-Neumann Algebra
I was going through the von-Neumann Algebra book by Anantharaman and Popa. I came across the convolution product in group von-Neumann algebras. I understood the definition of convolution product. However, I cannot understand the meaning of the symbol $L_f$. It seems to be an operator on $\ell^2(G)$. In addition, how do we get such an expression of $L_f$ when $f$ is of finite support (the highlighted part). Also, please let me know if there are more easy explanations (references) of the same.

For your first question, yes, $L_f$ is an operator on $\ell^2(G)$. It is the operator which for fixed $f$ gives $L_f(f_1) = f * f_1$ for any $f_1 \in \ell^2(G)$.

@LSK21 Thank you for your comment. Can you kindly tell something about the highlighted part?

As mentioned in my comment, $L_f$ is an operator on $\ell^2(G)$, specifically it is the operator which for given $f$ yields $L_f(f_1) = f * f_1$ for any $f_1 \in \ell^2(G)$.
As for the highlighted part, the formula should be relatively clear: Let $f_1 \in \ell^2(G).$ For any $t \in G$ we have
$$\left(\sum_{s \in G} f(s) \lambda(s) \right)(f_1)(t) = \sum_{s \in G} f(s) \lambda(s) f_1(t) = \sum_{s \in G} f(s) f_1(s^{-1}t)$$
by definition of the left-regular representation $\lambda$.
In addition, the text mentions that for any choice of $f \in \ell^2(G)$, $L_f(f_1) = f* f_1$ is in $\ell^\infty(G)$. However, when $f$ has finite support, the convolution product is even in $\ell^2(G)$. Let us prove this quickly:
\begin{align}
\|f*f_1\|_2^2 &= \sum_{t \in G}|(f*g)(t)|^2 \\
&= \sum_{t \in G} \left| \sum_{s \in S} f(s) f_1(s^{-1}t) \right|^2 \quad, \text{where } S := \text{supp}(f) \\
&\leq \sum_{t \in G} \left( \sum_{s \in S} |f(s)|^2 \right) \left( \sum_{s \in S} |f_1(s^{-1}t)|^2 \right) \quad \text{by Cauchy-Schwarz} \\
&= \|f\|_2^2 \sum_{s \in S} \sum_{t \in G} |f_1(s^{-1}t)|^2 \\
&= \|f\|_2^2 \|f_1\|_2^2 |S| < \infty.
\end{align}
Note that $\sum_{t \in G} |f_1(s^{-1}t)|^2$ is just the squared $\ell^2$ norm of $f_1$, since $G$ is a group and therefore closed under the group action.
